# Keras: Time CNN+LSTM for video recognition

Tags: keras, lstm

[image: Proposed deep learning model]

I am trying to implement the Model shown in the above picture that basically consists of time-distributed CNNs followed by a sequence of LSTMs using Keras with TF.
I have divided two types of class, and extract the frames from each video captured. The frames extract is variable, do not fix.

However, I am having a problem trying to figure out How can I load my image frames for each video in each class to become `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(
TimeDistributed(
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'), 
    input_shape=(data.num_frames, data.width, data.height, 1)
   )
)
```

I don't know how to type in the `data.num_frames` if each video contains n different number of frames extracted.

The inputs are small videos just 3-8 seconds (i.e. a sequence of frames).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `None` since this dimension doesn't affect the number of trainable weights of your model.

You will have problems, though, to create a batch of videos with numpy, since numpy doesn't accept variable sizes.

You can train each video individually, or you can create dummy frames (zero padding) to make all videos reach the same max length. Then use a `Masking` layer to ignore these frames. (Certain Keras versions have problems when using `TimeDistributed` + `Masking`)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this method. Could you provide the similar coding for the masking layer?

Comment: If I want to train each video individually, how would be the implementation?

Comment: Now, I have fixed the number of frames to 10. If I have a fixed frame number, the next step is to load the data into the CNN for each video. How can i do that?

Comment: Read the `model.fit()` or `model.fit_generator()` methods: https://keras.io/models/sequential/